# [Xamarin][Mvvmcross] Failed to lookup the required marshalling information

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I'm following mvvmcross [tutorial](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/tutorials/tipcalc/a-xamarinios-ui-project?scroll=1909.0908203125) for iOS project. I think I'm doing exactly for is described there, but when I run the appliaction I'm getting following error:

```
ObjCRuntime.RuntimeException
  Message=Failed to lookup the required marshalling information.
Additional information:
    Selector: setGenerositySlider:
    Type: TipView

  Source=
  StackTrace:
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.2.0.12/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:86 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0000e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.2.0.12/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:65 
  at TipCalc.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\source\repos\xamarin\TipCalc.Core\TipCalc.iOS\Main.cs:12
```

I cloned the same project from the samples and it runs fine. I think I compared everything I could and projects are the same as far as I can tell.

```
namespace TipCalc.iOS
{
    public class Application
    {
        // This is the main entry point of the application.
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
            // you can specify it here.
            UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
        }        
    }
}
```

```
namespace TipCalc.iOS
{
    [Register(nameof(AppDelegate))]
    public class AppDelegate : MvxApplicationDelegate<MvxIosSetup<App>, App>
    {
        public override UIWindow Window { get; set; }

        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {
            var result = base.FinishedLaunching(application, launchOptions);

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

```
public partial class TipView : MvxViewController<TipViewModel>
    {
        public TipView() : base(nameof(TipView), null)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<TipView, TipViewModel>();
            set.Bind(TipLabel).To(vm => vm.Tip);
            set.Bind(SubTotalTextField).To(vm => vm.SubTotal);
            set.Bind(GenerositySlider).To(vm => vm.Generosity);
            set.Apply();

            View.AddGestureRecognizer(new UITapGestureRecognizer(() =>
            {
                this.SubTotalTextField.ResignFirstResponder();
            }));
        }
    }
```

Generated code behind

```
namespace TipCalc.iOS
{
    [Register ("TipView")]
    partial class TipView
    {
        [Outlet]
        [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
        UISlider GenerositySlider { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
        UITextField SubTotalTextField { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
        UILabel TipLabel { get; set; }

        void ReleaseDesignerOutlets ()
        {
            if (GenerositySlider != null) {
                GenerositySlider.Dispose ();
                GenerositySlider = null;
            }

            if (SubTotalTextField != null) {
                SubTotalTextField.Dispose ();
                SubTotalTextField = null;
            }

            if (TipLabel != null) {
                TipLabel.Dispose ();
                TipLabel = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Doesn't seem to have anything to do with MvvmCross, but rather an issue with your storyboard. You can check the complete sample here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/TipCalc

Comment: I think the problem is that in the tutorial it says to add ViewController, and that will generate 3 classes. When I add ViewController it adds two classes in one file: UniversalView : UIView, UIViewController1 : UIViewController, and no XIB file.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't set File's Owners class, adding it resolved the problem.
[image]