# Xamarin.ios, Failed to lookup the required marshalling information

Tags: c#, xcode, xamarin.ios

I am trying to use an outlet to alter the text in a TextField, but whenever I make any reference to the outlet, I receive an error saying "Failed to lookup the required marshaling information". I am new to Xamarin.IOS, and working with Xcode, and I have searched for an answer to my issue but there is nothing that fixes my issue.

[ClientClass.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtXEv.png)

[ClientClass.designer.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9WCF.png)

[Inspector of ViewController using ClientClass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0YSt.png)

Comment: Per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64599871/xamarinmvvmcross-failed-to-lookup-the-required-marshalling-information), adding `Use Auto Layout` and `Use size classes` will solve the issue.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT the thread you referred to isn’t the Xcode interface editor, and also the fix for that person issue had nothing to do with Use Auto and Use Size Classes. It was the fact he didn’t have a class name. I’ve seen this post and it isn’t the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, The issue with my case is I wasn't writing my code in the correct method. I guess you have to write your code in the ViewDidLoad method as I understand.